# How to process file uploaded via Dropzone in Drupal?

Tags: drupal-7, dropzone.js

Recently I have been trying to process files uploaded via Dropzone.js in Drupal. I am not using the Drupal API form stuff, just a plain HTML code to generate Dropzone, but I want to process uploaded files using Drupal functions (`file_save_upload()`, in particular). However, I am not able to "catch" the uploaded file using the function.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, the `$_FILES` array generated by Dropzone, looks like this:

```
Array   (
    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => 5bcb9c.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /private/var/tmp/phpgZHmT8
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 273794
        )   )
```

However, Drupal's function file_save_upload() is awaiting the $_FILES array in this structure:

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [files] => 5bcb9c.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [files] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [files] => /private/var/tmp/php4ebqBs
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [files] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [files] => 210075
                )

        )

)
```

so what I had to do was to change the $_FILES variable (yes, I know!) so it matches the structure required by Drupal. It works now, although I do not quite understand why Dropzone generates another structure and Drupal requires other structure of the $_FILES variable. If anyone can elaborate on this, I would be glad. Nevertheless, my solution works.

Comment: seriously? I noticed the same, but assumed this just can not be true.. WHY? Both differ from what is written in the first comment here: http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: Very useful answer, soon I'll try to implement Dropzone in one of my projects. Dropzone seems a very interesting way to upload files. Plupload is similar, but it seems that Dropzone is better. The way that your $_FILES are uploaded could be a specific configuration of your server?